# Is there a way to stop/start the Windows Vista print spooler from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, print-spooler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restart a windows service from command](https://superuser.com/questions/301765/restart-a-windows-service-from-command)

Having trouble with the spooler, and stopping/restarting it is the "fix", but it's tedious to navigate through the menus to reach Services to restart.  Is there a way to stop/start a Windows "service" via the command line?

Comment: @DarthAndroid -- Thanks -- I guess I didn't hit the right search  keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using `cmd` as admin (run as administrator).

To stop the spooler, type `net stop spooler`,  i.e. `C:\windows\system32\net stop spooler`

This should work in Windows Vista.