# Windows: Right click on desktop causing hourglass hang

Tags: windows, freeze, context-menu

When I right click on the desktop, to invoke the context menu, an hourglass appears, forever, but no context menu. I've lost the ability to use the context menu but only on the desktop. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible options! Both restart the "NVIDIA Display Container LS" service... since NVIDIA seems to be a common culprit for this bug. Successfully tested on Windows 10... the first one uses the command line, the second one does not:

**Option 1:**

1. Press the Windows Key and the "R" key simultaneously to open "Run".
2. Type *cmd* and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to open as an Admin.
3. Now, type or paste the following into the command line and press enter:

- *net stop "NVIDIA Display Container LS" && net start "NVIDIA Display Container LS"*

IMG 1: [Open CMD with "Run"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARBgI.png)

IMG 2: [Restart NVIDIA Display Container LS with CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xujfw.png)

IMG 3: [Completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQtBK.png)

**Option 2:**

1. Press the Windows Key and the "R" key simultaneously to open "Run".
2. Type *services.msc* and press enter.
3. Find "NVIDIA Display Container LS"
4. Right-click and "Restart"

IMG 1: [Open "services.msc" with "Run"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udq2c.jpg)

IMG 2: [Restart NVIDIA Display Container LS with "services.msc"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYsbg.png)

Hope this helps any passersby! Peace and God bless!

Comment: Just as a quick heads up, the options I put together above were compiled from the following sources:
.....................
[1] https://superuser.com/questions/301765/restart-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line/301766#301766

[2] https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-the-nvidia-control-panel-not-opening-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

The issue is commonly caused by mischievous 3rd party context menu options. As recommended in the link below, I used [Nirsoft's ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to hunt down the offending entries. In my case, it was three Nvidia's context menu entries. I disabled them and all is good. I'm sure a newer version of Nvidia's context menus, or re-installation of Nvidia software, would fix the issue.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/11e9d879-cc8a-412e-b158-9310b4f4a4fb/explorer-hang-right-click-hour-glass?forum=winserverTS

[image]